# How to add class to the element that contains a certain string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this li list:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

How can I add a class "item-3" to the li element that contains "item 3" between the `<li>` and `</li>` tags?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

```
$('li:contains("item 3")').addClass('item-3');
```

From the docs (http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in
>   any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with
>   attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains()
>   can be written as bare words or surrounded by quotation marks. The
>   text must have matching case to be selected.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/2wcqW/

Comment: Just as a side-note: the `:contains()` selector is case-sensitive. Case-insensitive searches require `.filter()` and a custom function.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === 'item 3'
}).addClass('yourClass');
```

Comment: +1 FWIW, this is the fastest method between: `:contains()`, `$.each()` and `.filter()`. Here's some proof: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-contains

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('ul li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === "item 3") {
      $(this).addClass('item-3');
    }
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srpAX/

Comment: +1 FWIW; This is faster than using `:contains`. Here is a jsperf to prove: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-contains

Comment: @Jasper I'd never seen that sight before. Amazing.

Comment: Is filter ALWAYS the fastest way to do this kind of task or is it situation specific?

Comment: @Zero21xxx I couldn't say off the top of my head. I generally use jsperf in a specific situation to see what is the fastest method. Something to remember is that different browsers will give different results and this is especially true with old browsers (...IE6).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li:contains("item 3")').addClass('item-3');
```

Comment: will work correctly, but I do not think it is necessary to first select on ULs

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "Item 3"){
        $(this).addClass("item-3");
    }
});
```